# Talend split fields from one to double

Tags: talend

I have mysql table with text field "email", which can contain "user@example.com" and "user1@example.com;user2@example.com;user3@example.com".

```
| Name    | Email                                                  |
| user    | user@example.com                                       |
| user1   | user1@example.com;user2@example.com;user3@example.com  |
```

How can i do output with Talend such this:

```
| Name    | Email              |
| user    | user@example.com   |
| user1   | user1@example.com  |
| user1   | user2@example.com  |
| user1   | user3@example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *tNormalize* component does exactly this. You can provide a character for separation, in your case `;` and get rows as result afterwards.

**EDIT**

AxelH pointed out that it is possible as well to use a `String` for separation, this is not a `Character`.

Comment: I never get why it is called like this... I always struggle to remember the name of that component